# HTML/CSS How to put together Image/Icon with a text?

Tags: html, css

I want to have the icon for the login be clickable and over the "LOGIN" Text centered. Furthermore I want that on the navbar/sidebar all images/icons are always in a pair with the text that belongs to it, like "LOGIN" and the login icon over it or with the registration. If you find ways to fix it & find ways how to fix my code to make it more efficient, I will be very pleased. Any suggestions? I hope smb can help, thanks!

```css
body{
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

a.nounderline{
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #1478a0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Alef', sans-serif;

}

a.nounderline span{
  color: #ffffff;
}

div.container{
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #000000;
  
}

.floating-menu{
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Changa One', cursive;
  font-size: 16px;
  top:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-50%);
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  height: 42%;
}


  .absoluteCenterWrapper {
    position:relative;
   }
   .absoluteCenter {
    margin:auto; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0;
    bottom:0; 
   }
   .absoluteCenter { 
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
   }

a.new_paragraph span {
  line-height: 0em;
  display: block;
}

.main-menu{
  margin: 0;
  padding:  0;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  list-style: none;
 
}.main-menu li a{
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  line-height: 3em;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: auto;
  position: relative; 
  top: 36px;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  
}

.main-menu li a:hover{
  color: #1478a0;
}

.menu-bg{
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius:55px;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Access Denied">
    <meta name="author" content="AccessDenied">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Social Media">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AccessDenied</title>
   
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Changa+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Teko:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alef:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
    
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
 
    <header>
        <div class="container">
          <a href="index.html" class="nounderline">ACCESS<span>DENIED</span></a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <aside>
      </aside>
    </main>
    <sidebar>
      <nav class="floating-menu">
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.google.com" class="absoluteCenterWrapper"> 
                <img src="http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_311846.png" class="absoluteCenter">
                <span>LOGIN</span>
              </a>
                    
              </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" >REGISTER</a>
               
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="new_paragraph" >GET<span>PREMIUM</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="menu-bg"></div>
          
      </nav>
    </sidebar>
    <footer>
    </footer>

  </body>





</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

I changed the link label from `<span>` into `<div>` and added `.icon` class.

```css
body{
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

a.nounderline{
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #1478a0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Alef', sans-serif;

}

a.nounderline span{
  color: #ffffff;
}

div.container{
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #000000;
  
}

.floating-menu{
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: 'Changa One', cursive;
  font-size: 16px;
  top:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-50%);
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  height: 42%;
}


  .absoluteCenterWrapper {
    position:relative;
   }
   .absoluteCenter {
    margin:auto; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0;
    bottom:0; 
   }
   .absoluteCenter { 
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
   }

a.new_paragraph span {
  line-height: 0em;
  display: block;
}

.main-menu{
  margin: 0;
  padding:  0;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  list-style: none;
 
}
.main-menu li a{
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  line-height: 3em;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: auto;
  position: relative; 
  top: 36px;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  
}

.main-menu li a:hover{
  color: #1478a0;
}

.menu-bg{
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius:55px;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.icon {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Access Denied">
    <meta name="author" content="AccessDenied">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Social Media">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AccessDenied</title>
   
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Changa+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Teko:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alef:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
    
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
 
    <header>
        <div class="container">
          <a href="index.html" class="nounderline">ACCESS<span>DENIED</span></a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <aside>
      </aside>
    </main>
    <sidebar>
      <nav class="floating-menu">
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.google.com" class="absoluteCenterWrapper"> 
                <img class="icon" src="http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_311846.png" class="absoluteCenter">
                <div>LOGIN</div>
              </a>
                    
              </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="menu-bg"></div>
          
      </nav>
    </sidebar>
    <footer>
    </footer>

  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But now there is way too much space between the icon and the text. How can you fix that?

Comment: You can adjust `line-height` on this selector `.main-menu li a` to 2em or anything you like

Answer (score -1):

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
nav {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 20px;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
nav ul li a img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
nav ul li span {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.google.com">
            <img src="https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_311846.png" />
            <span>LOGIN</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.google.com">
            <img src="https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_311846.png" />
            <span>LOGIN</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.google.com">
            <img src="https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_311846.png" />
            <span>LOGIN</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.google.com">
            <img src="https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_311846.png" />
            <span>LOGIN</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```